# Python Denary to Binary Convertor

Tags: python, binary

Hi can you please help me convert denary values to binary and hex? I have to input a number between 0 and 15 and the output should be its hexadecimal and binary equivalent. Here's what I've done so far:

```
    denary_list=           ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"]
    print("denary list")


binary_list=["0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"]
print("binary list")

hex_list=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"]
print("hex list")
option=input("enter choice:\n1.print values\n2.convert denary number to binary and hex\n3. Convert a hex value between 0 and 15 to denary or binary value\n9. Quit")
if option=='1':
   print ("denary","\t","binary","hex")
   count1=0
   while count1<len(denarylist) and count1<len(binarylist) and count1<len(hexlist):
       print(denarylist[count1],"\t",binarylist[count1],"\t",hexlist[count1])
       count1+=1
if option=='2':
  number=int(input("what number do you choose to convert to binary and hex"))
  if number<=15 and number>=0:
```

Comment: What is it you are struggling with? It seems to me all you need to do is `print binary_list[num]` and `print hex_list[num]` at the end of your code.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `format` method instead with `b` and `x` format codes to format integers as hexadecimal or binary numbers:

```
>>> format(1234, 'b')
'10011010010'
>>> format(1234, 'x')
'4d2'
```

Use `int('01234fff', 16)` to convert a hex string into a number; likewise `int('11110000', 2)` to convert a binary string into a number.

---

And to answer your original question: you can get **number**th item (zero-based indexing) with `binary_list[number]` and so you can write your option 2 as

```
number = int(input("what number do you choose to convert to binary and hex"))
if 0 <= number <= 15:
    print("the number in binary is", binary_list[number])
    print("the number in hex is", hex_list[number])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm new to programming and here is what was i need: (using the lists of binary & hex numbers - for this option, input a number between 0 and 15 and output binary & hex equivalent)   Will your suggestion be enough?

Answer (score 1):

This is My own version of a denary to binary converter:

```
Number = int(input("Enter a number to convert: ")) 

if Number < 0:
    print ("Can't be less than 0")
else:
    Remainder = 0
    String = ""
    while Number > 0:
        Remainder = Number % 2
        Number = Number //2
        String = str(Remainder) + String
    print (String)
```